# executing shell script using subprocess.Popen in Python?

Tags: python, json, bash, shell

I am trying to execute shell script from the Python program. And instead of using `subprocess.call`, I am using `subprocess.Popen` as I want to see the output of the shell script and error if any while executing the shell script in a variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import json
import socket
import os

jsonStr = '{"script":"#!/bin/bash\\necho Hello world\\n"}'
j = json.loads(jsonStr)

shell_script = j['script']

print shell_script

print "start"
proc = subprocess.Popen(shell_script, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if stderr:
   print "Shell script gave some error"
   print stderr
else:
   print stdout
   print "end" # Shell script ran fine.
```

But the above code whenever I am running, I am always getting error like this -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 29, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shell_script, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any idea what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute an arbitrary shell script given as a string, just add `shell=True` parameter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import call
from textwrap import dedent

call(dedent("""\
    #!/bin/bash
    echo Hello world
    """), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it with `shell=True` (you can leave out the shebang, too).

`proc = subprocess.Popen(j['script'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()`

Or, you could just do:

`proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'Hello world'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Or, you could write the script to file, then invoke it:

```
inf = open('test.sh', 'wb')
inf.write(j['script'])
inf.close()

print "start"
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sh', 'test.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
```