# How do I execute this line of code in a python script as if it were command line?

Tags: python, jython

I'm trying to write a script to duplicate running the line:

```
    D:\...\bin>jython.bat D:\...\UploadTest.py
```

in a python script, like it were via cmd. I've tried a variety of subprocess.Popen commands and none of them work (all get the Errno2 file not found). I currently have

```
    subprocess.Popen([r'D:\...\bin\jython.bat', r'D:\...\UploadTest.py'])
```

and I have tried several other variations. I'm mainly concerned with the space between the .bat and .py portions of the command. Should I just use r'' with a space between the two?

Comment: `r''` or `'\\'`, not both.

Comment: Have you tried just importing the module if it is on your python path? Importing and running the script are the same unless there is an import guard.

Comment: Use os.path.join to prevent using slashes. It is a multi-platform method. [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: @MadPhysicist would that work if i want to run the .bat and the .py as one line? Kind of like an argument I guess (I'm not good with the vocab of coding)

Comment: I am making some assumptions here. Assumption #1 is that the code that you have the `Popen` call in is being run by jython. Assumption #2 is that `UploadTest.py` has no import guard (line that says `if __name__ == '__main__'`). If both are true, replace `suborocess.Popen...` with `import UploadTest.py`. If `UploadTest.py` is not on your python path, do `sys.path.append('D:\\folder\\containing\\the\\script')` first.

Comment: I'm not on a windows machine right now, but you can use Popen. Start cmd.exe (don't know where it is) with -c i think, followed by your commands. It will tell cmd to run these.

Comment: @MadPhysicist jython.bat calls jython, so I believe your first assumption is correct. The Uploadtest.py does have an import guard, though.

Comment: @burghermeister. Could you post the contents of the import guard? Is it just a single call to something like `run()`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist why do you suggest adding the .py's directory to the import path if he is writing the absolute path?

Comment: @Hamlett OP is writing the absolute path in the call to `Popen`. I am suggesting moving away from that entirely and executing the module from within his script without starting a separate process. To do that, it may be necessary to point python to the correct folder.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it's a script that uploads a file to a server that's set up. everything in the script is under the guard. I'm just trying to figure out how to duplicate running the .bat, followed by the .py with a space in between, as if it were from cmd

Comment: Please show the exact error message. And if possible, say whether it is a Python exception in calling script, and error in the batch file, or an error in Jython.

Comment: @SergeBallesta IOError: [Errno 2] File not found - D:\...\UploadTest.py (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: From cmd, do `dir D:\...\UploadTest.py`. Fix the path until it works, then paste it back in.

Comment: Did you control twice (copy/paste in console) that D:\...\UploadTest.py actually exists?

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to use `shell=True` in the POpen call. But note the warnings about potential security issues found in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's an attempt to answer the question. If you know this doesn't answer the question, could you provide more information please?

Comment: The error *File not found* suggest that the problem is not really there...

Answer (score -1):

I had tried something like this. Let me know if this suits your requirement. Here is the reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810366/executing-shell-script-using-subprocess-popen-in-python)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import call
from textwrap import dedent

call(dedent("""\
    #!/bin/bash
    echo Hello world
    """), shell=True)
```

Comment: I doubt a guy running jython from a batch script is going to have success running a script in bash.